# using law of cosines to find the equivalent vector

Tags: vectors

> let there $\vec{A}=10cm$, $\vec{B}=15cm$ and the angle between them $25$ degrees, find the the equivalent vector $\vec{C}$

So we have: $|\vec{A}|=10$, $|\vec{B}|=15$, $\theta=25$

Using the law of cosines $C^2=A^2+B^2-2AB\cos\theta$ we have $|\vec{C}|^2=|\vec{A}|^2+|\vec{B}|^2-2|\vec{A}||\vec{B}|\cos\theta$

$|\vec{C}|^2=53.1\rightarrow |\vec{C}|=7.28$

But the current answer is 24.43 where did I get it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working backwards from the answer, your 'equivalent vector' is the sum of the other two vectors: $\vec C = \vec A + \vec B$.  What you have calculated is the length of $\vec A - \vec B$.

See [this page](http://www.animations.physics.unsw.edu.au/jw/vectors.htm#add) for a diagram showing the situation. You can see how there is an acute angle between the vectors, but when you translate one of the vectors to make them head-to-tail for addition, you end up using an obtuse angle to calculate $\vec C$.

Comment: I see, so I need to take the angle between $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{B}$ after I made them head-to-tail? but how can I find it if I know that $|\vec{A}|\neq |\vec{B}|$?

Comment: @gbox: Are you talking about the angle between $\vec A$ and $\vec B$ after you move one of them to make them head-to-tail?  The moved vector is parallel to the original vector, so geometrically you've got a line intersecting a pair of parallel lines.

Comment: so the angle will be 180-25=165?

Comment: @gbox: Correct.